# Android youtube comment API

Tags: android, youtube, google-api

In my application, user is required to log in with google account first and then later when they view youtube video, they can comment without log in to authenticate.

I wonder which kind of services do I need to use to enable comment?
There are so many services but I cannot find youtube:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert

```
Post url : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! How to use it in Andorid?